Mongoose Validation Error: Cast to [undefined] Failed for ObjectId Fields
I'm facing an issue with Mongoose when creating a new VendorContract that is supposed to reference a Vendor document. Despite the fact that my code is passing correct ObjectIds for fields like pointOfContact and vendorContracts, Mongoose is throwing validation errors, indicating that it's receiving entire objects rather than ObjectIds.
Problem Details
I have two Mongoose models: Vendor and VendorContract. The Vendor model has fields like pointOfContact and vendorContracts, which are arrays of ObjectIds. The VendorContract model contains references to the Vendor document.
When I try to create a new VendorContract, I receive the following error:
Vendor validation failed: pointOfContact.0: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"66e6b0dcb015052939918457","name":"Lucifer morningstar","email":"lucifermorningstar@example.com","phoneNumber":"321-654-0987"}]" (type string) at path "pointOfContact.0", 
vendorContracts.0: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"billingDetails":["66de926d236023d8c8e02ccf"],"clientContracts":["66d3f28562f3d66fc4fbd2fb","66d3f28462f3d66fc4fbd04b"], ...]" (type string) at path "vendorContracts.0", 
address: Path `address` is required.

Code Overview
Here’s the relevant structure of my two models:
Vendor Model:
const vendorMongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  pointOfContact: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "ContactDetail",
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  vendorContracts: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "VendorContract",
    },
  ],
  address: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Address",
  },
  createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  updatedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

export default mongoose.model("Vendor", vendorMongooseSchema);

VendorContract Model:
const vendorContractMongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  vendorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Vendor", required: true },
  contractNumber: { type: String, required: true },
  billingDetails: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "BillingDetail", required: true }],
  clientContracts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ClientContract" }],
  contractStartDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  onBoardingDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  signedContractCopy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Media", required: true },
  expiryDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  uploadedFiles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Media", required: true }],
  pointOfContact: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ContactDetail" }],
  status: { type: String, enum: ["active", "inactive"], default: "active" },
  fieldEngineers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "FieldEngineer" }],
  createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  updatedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
});

export default mongoose.model("VendorContract", vendorContractMongooseSchema);

Code to Create VendorContract
Here’s the code I’m using to create a new VendorContract:
async createVendorContract(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
  try {
    req.body = await processReferences(req.body, models, "vendorContracts", req.userId);
    console.log("Processed req.body after processReferences:", req.body);

    const contract = await vendorService.createVendorContract(req.body);
    if (!contract) {
      throw new Error("Failed to create the vendor contract.");
    }

    res.status(201).json(contract);
  } catch (error: any) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}

In the createVendorContract method, I call processReferences, which converts nested objects into ObjectIds. After processing, the req.body looks like this (which appears to be correct):
{
  vendorId: '66e6b0dcb01505293991845a',
  contractNumber: 'vc-0329',
  uploadedFiles: [ '66db3ddd55d1f68b9443379c', '66e0077813cb320e23a39858' ],
  billingDetails: [ '66de926d236023d8c8e02ccf' ],
  pointOfContact: [ '66e857354254d67a3d78a666' ],
  expiryDate: '2025-09-01',
  contractStartDate: '2024-08-31',
  onBoardingDate: '2024-09-01',
  signedContractCopy: '66d9db21e980ea65d81c5911',
  clientContracts: [
    '66d3f28562f3d66fc4fbd2fb',
    '66d3f28462f3d66fc4fbd04b',
    '66d3f28762f3d66fc4fbd4fb',
    '66d3f28762f3d66fc4fbd56b',
    '66d3f28462f3d66fc4fbd10b'
  ],
  status: 'active',
  fieldEngineers: [],
  updatedBy: '66bcc6b5776153713cdcb7a9',
  createdBy: '66bcc6b5776153713cdcb7a9'
}

The Issue
Despite having the correct ObjectIds in the fields like pointOfContact and vendorContracts, I am still receiving the following error when attempting to save the contract:
Vendor validation failed: pointOfContact.0: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"66e6b0dcb015052939918457","name":"Lucifer morningstar","email":"lucifermorningstar@example.com","phoneNumber":"321-654-0987"}]" (type string) at path "pointOfContact.0",
vendorContracts.0: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[...]" (type string) at path "vendorContracts.0",
address: Path `address` is required.

It seems like Mongoose is trying to cast entire objects into ObjectIds, even though I'm already passing valid ObjectIds.
I Have Tried

Checked processReferences: I’ve ensured that the processReferences function is correctly converting nested objects into ObjectIds before saving.
Verified Data: I logged the req.body after processing, and it shows the expected ObjectIds for the pointOfContact and vendorContracts fields.
Checked Vendor Document: The Vendor document has the required address field, and pointOfContact is an array of ObjectIds.

My Questions

Why is Mongoose attempting to cast entire objects (e.g., pointOfContact and billingDetails) when I am already providing ObjectIds?
Could this issue be related to how Mongoose is hydrating the related Vendor document when trying to save the VendorContract?
How can I ensure that Mongoose only references ObjectIds and doesn't attempt to validate or cast embedded objects in this case?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
